# Graphql query filter in Weaviate

Tags: graphql, weaviate

It seems I can't figure out how to query the Weaviate and filter out unwanted objects.
I have read: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments

I think this would translate into my test using postman:

```
{ 
  "query": "{ 
    Get { 
      Things { 
        Technique(name: "some name of technique in the weaviate") { name, uuid } 
      } 
    } 
  }"
}
```

This results I received:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "parsing body body from \"\" failed, because invalid character 's' after object key:value pair"
}
```

How should this work?

Comment: As a tip, you can also use the [playground](http://playground.semi.technology/) (after getting access, click GRAPHQL QUERYING in the right top) to test your GraphQL queries directly

Comment: In the playground the query described in the answer of @LauraHam works. But in Postman I still recieve errors. 
The body I send is:
{"query": "{ Get { Things { Technique ( where: { path: ["name"], operator: Equal, valueString: "Audio Capture"} ) { name, uuid } } } }" }

Comment: Can you please share the complete request? Is it a POST with JSON headers?

Comment: Yes I did but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out objects in Weaviate you have to use the "where" filter. Take a look here: https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/query-data/filters.html#where-filter.

I think your query in GrapiQL would look something like this:

> {"query": "{ Get { Things { Technique ( where: { path: ["name"],
>   operator: Equal, valueSting: "some name of technique in the weaviate"}
>   ) { name, uuid } } } }" }

For a JSON body in a rest POST request, it would look like this (escape the double quotes):

> {"query": "{ Get { Things { Technique ( where: { path: [\"name\"],
>   operator: Equal, valueSting: \"some name of technique in the weaviate\"}
>   ) { name, uuid } } } }" }

Comment: Ah thanks! I have seen this somewhere and tried that before.

this results in:


{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "parsing body body from \"\" failed, because invalid character 'n' after object key:value pair"
}

Comment: The query is perfect though, it just doesn't work if it is send using Postman.

Comment: Did you specify that the body is in json format? It's seems to try to parse a key/value pair.

Comment: I managed to execute the query now, I did not escape the double quotes, this resulted in these errors.

So the body that should be provided looks like this:

{"query": "{ Get { Things { Technique ( where: { path: [\"name\"], operator: Equal, valueString: \"some name value here\"} ) { name, uuid } } } }" }